# Run python zip file from memory at runtime?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python zip file which is retrieved using requests.get. The zip file has several directories of python files in addition to the __main__.py, so in the interest of easily sending it as a single file, I am zipping it.

I know the file is being sent correctly, as I can save it to a file and then run it, however, I want to execute it without writing it to storage.

The working part is more or less as follows:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://myurl.com/get_zip")
```

I can write the zip to file using

```
f = open("myapp.zip","wb")
f.write(response.content)
f.close()
```

and manually run it from command line. However, I want something more like

```
exec(response.content)
```

This doesn't work since it's still compressed, but you get the idea.

I am also open to ideas that replace the zip with some other format of sending the code over internet, if it's easier to execute it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is this

```py
import io
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

response = requests.get("http://myurl.com/get_zip")
# Read the contents of the zip into a bytes object.
binary_zip = io.BytesIO(response.content)
# Convert the bytes object into a ZipFile.
zip_file = ZipFile(binary_zip, "r")
# Iterate over all files in the zip (folders should be also ok).
for script_file in zip_file.namelist():
    exec(zip_file.read(script_file))
```

But it is a bit convoluted and probably can be improved.